# Delete user and change Content Author

Tags: 7, users

Is it possible to Delete the user and keep its content as created by the one who deleted the user.

Suppose, **abc** is a user as *content creator/editor* only and have created 2 contents.

**abc** got fired as editor and his boss **xyz** wants to delete his user account.

**xyz** not only wants to delete **abc** but while deleting **abc** transfer all the content created by **abc** to his name, so that it'd be like created by **xyz**.

Drupal has only 4 options while deleting user account which doesn't satisfy this need.

If it is possible then how? please elaborate how to achieve that....

Answer (score 2):

While canceling user account choose either `Disable the user account and keep its content` or `content belong to anonymous user`

[image]

---

**To bulk Update author for node you could use [Views Bulk Operation](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations)**

- Create a view listing the content that you want to edit.
- Add a bulk operation in fields

[image]

- Select change the author of the content

[image]

- Go to your view to select the nodes for which you want to change the author

[image]

- Select the author who should be made the new other for all these content.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is an option while deleting a user that `Cancel the user account and keep its content`.

To change the author you may need to implement [hook_user_delete](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.api.php/function/hook_user_delete/7).

Answer (score 0):

You can implement [`hook_user_cancel_methods_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.api.php/function/hook_user_cancel_methods_alter/7.x) to add your own cancellation methods. Add the cancellation methods using this hook, then implement [`hook_user_cancel()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.api.php/function/hook_user_cancel/7.x).

In the hook_user_cancel implementation, you will be able to use a switch/case on the method selected and create your custom cancellation logic:

- Load the entities
- Change the uid for each one the user owned/created
- Change the uid for fields pointing at this user
- Save the entities